# Why doesn't the width of my textinput box match the width of the Bootstrap grid I have written in my form/html?

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-forms, datagrid

I'm using a Bootstrap grid and setting the width of the first column to md-6.  The screen shot below shows that the control is indeed getting set to the desired width, but the textinput box is not expanding.  I've done this before in other projects and I can get the widths to change correctly in those projects.  I have simplified the form and html and tried to look for differences between the projects.  I'm blind to the problem at this point.  I'd like some ideas on new things to try.

Here is my html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Create Work item{% endblock %}

{% block moreheaders %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    {{ form.media }}    
{% endblock %}


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}      

{% block content %}
    <form action= "{% url 'save' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-row">
                
                <div class="form-group col-md-6  mb-0">
                    {{ form.itemnumber|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.priority|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3  mb-0">
                    {{ form.type|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my form:

```html
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from tempus_dominus.widgets import DatePicker, TimePicker, DateTimePicker
from django.utils.text import slugify
from workitems.models import *
import datetime




class WorkitemForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Workitem

    
    itemnumber = forms.CharField()
    priority = forms.IntegerField()
    type = forms.CharField(initial="I")
    
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("args=",args)
        if "request.POST" in kwargs:
            self.request = kwargs.pop(request.POST)
        else:
            if "request" in kwargs:
                self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(WorkitemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image: Screenshot of Chrome debugger showing textinput box and div widths]

Answer (score 0):

I created another project and the textinput box widths started to behave.  Something was corrupted, but I don;t know what it was.